# Log both at dev console and at running node console instance

Tags: javascript, electron

I need to log to the chromium console from the main process in an Electron app, where `win` is the BrowserWindow, like so:

```
function logEverywhere(s) {
  console.log(s)
  if (win && win.webContents) {
    win.webContents.executeJavaScript(`console.log("${s}")`)
  }
}
```

However, this only logs in the running node console instance, and if I remove the `if` statement, it returns an error saying `win.webContents` is undefined.

How do I fix this?

Comment: If you use Electron's [IPC modules](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main) this is for sure possible